# Asp.Net/Sitecore embedded ascx resources not picking up changes

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, assemblies, sitecore

I'm not sure if this is a Sitecore 6 or Asp.net problem.

I have an assembly made up entirely of ascx user controls in which all of the necessary files are embedded resources (ascx, javascript, etc). I have been using the user controls in this assembly in a Sitecore web site for a few months.

Recently I tried to make changes to some of the user controls. I'm sure I made changes to the user controls in the past and it worked fine. But now when I make any changes to the ascx files they don't get picked up in the website. Changes to other files, including the code behind and javascript files are getting picked up. It appears only to be the ascx files that have a problem. It continues to use the old versions of the ascx files, from where I have no idea.

I know it's using the latest version of my assembly because I've stepped through the code behind, and used Fusion to check where the assemblies are loaded from. I've tried deleting all of the files in the Asp.Net cache. I've looked at the ascx files inside the assembly using a decompiler and it does have all of the changes I made. I turned off all caching in Sitecore just to see if that would fix it, but it didn't. I can't think of anything else to check. Any ideas?

Comment: Did your old assembly get put into the GAC maybe, and that version is being called?

Comment: No, I checked the GAC and it's not there.

Comment: Too late people, I figured it out myself. Seems there is a new flag in web.config compilation settings called optimizeCompilations that is supposed to make things compile faster. Someone set this to true and that caused changes to user controls in other assemblies to not get compiled.

Comment: Glad to know the fix. Please enter your answer below and mark it as the answer so other people can learn from it in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems there is a new flag in web.config compilation settings called optimizeCompilations that is supposed to make things compile faster. Someone set this to true and that caused changes to user controls in other assemblies to not get compiled